# Google Spreadsheets How to insert notes if source is in a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a code to insert notes in a range of cells the source or content of such notes is located in a different sheet, what I'm trying to accomplish is to paste what I have in cell C2 from Sheet1 into cell F2 (as a note) from "report" (that's the name of the target sheet) and then the same until it reaches the last row.

I came up with this:

```
function insertPhoneNumbers() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("report");
 var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var nrange = sourcesheet.getRange("C2", getLastRow()).getValue();
  var notes = targetsheet.getRange("F2", getLastRow());

 notes.setNotes(nrange)

}
```

But it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `getValues()` with an `s`. Otherwise, you're calling a different method that only gets a single value, as opposed to the 2D array you need.

Comment: Tried it still nothing

Comment: Is `nrange` empty or does it contain data, but notes are not being created?

Comment: It contains data but the notes are not being created

Comment: `getLastRow()` should be also be called on a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the cell value of C2 to a note on cell F2
You do not need to call getLastRow(). Also as there is only one note you better use setNote (whitout s) and never forget ";" at the end of a line.
Try the following code:

```
    function insertPhoneNumbers() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("report");
  var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var nrange = sourcesheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var notes = targetsheet.getRange("F2");
  notes.setNote(nrange);

}
```